# Elasticsearch(6.5) HIgh level java rest client Delete an index by name is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I can delete a document by passing the index name , type and id like this-

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(data.getIndexName(),data.getType(),data.getUniqueId());

    DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest);
```

But when I am trying to delete an index by giving the index name only like below- (According to this [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-delete-index.html))

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(allData.getIndexName());

    DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest);
```

getting-

```
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: id is missing;
```

I have tried another way like this ([reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-delete-index.html))

```
DeleteIndexRequest request = new DeleteIndexRequest(allData.getIndexName());
    AcknowledgedResponse deleteIndexResponse = client.indices().delete(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete(IndicesClient.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.5.4.jar:6.4.3]
```

I am using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
       <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
       <version>6.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] \- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level- 
client:jar:6.5.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure- 
sm:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x- 
content:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson- 
dataformat-smile:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson- 
dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson- 
dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers- 
common:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward- 
codecs:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.4.0:compile
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>search-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>search-service</name>
<description>Demo project for search-service</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
<version>6.7.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The second way is the right one. Weird it throws that error, though, as version 6.5.4 did have the `delete` method already.

Comment: Seems like correct version in not loading. Check if some some dependency is overriding the version.

Comment: @NishantSaini  I have added the dependency above which I have used. And its showing one warning-"Overriding managed version 6.4.3 for elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" in pom.xml. Is this the reason why delete index is not working

Comment: In the dependency tree check what version of elastic search (`org.elasticsearch`) is being used. This should be 6.5.4 or above.

Comment: @NishantSaini I have added the mvn dependency:tree don't know why it is showing 6.4.3? I have only the 6.5.4 dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Some other dependency might be indirectly overriding this. Can you add pom content?

Comment: @NishantSaini I have added the pom.xml

Comment: @Val could you please check again I have added some more details may be you can find something

Comment: @Bran: Just a hit and trial solution: add this property to the pom `<elasticsearch.version>6.5.4</elasticsearch.version>` and add the elastic dependency as `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @Bran is this solved?

Comment: @NishantSaini No I tried a lot of things but failed.so at last I use java low level rest client to achieve the requirement.

Comment: @Bran Have you tried making changes as per my last message?

Comment: @Bran Check my answer. I would suggest you not to go with low level rest client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring-boot v2.1.2 release has a property defined for elasticsearch version as

```
<elasticsearch.version>6.4.3</elasticsearch.version>
```

and the following dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the reason for this in dependency tree

> org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.4.3:compile

To force load elasticsearch 6.5.4 add the following property to your pom which will override the property defined in spring-boot-dependencies pom

```
<properties>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.5.4</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Yes It does the job.Thanks