# How to integrate ElasticSearch 7.0 version with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the latest version of Elastic Search library which is already available in the maven repos.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But not sure how can I use the 7th version with Spring Boot which imports 6.5. 
My maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` dependency add the `elasticsearch ` (version 7.0.0) version in your pom.xml file and you can use it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470686/elasticsearch6-5-high-level-java-rest-client-delete-an-index-by-name-is-not-wo/55529507#55529507) might help. Replace the version number to your needs.

Comment: doesn't work for me. if you replace "spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch" in the dependencies, you cant use the spring data features anymore, surprise. 
If you just add it like in the suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470686/elasticsearch6-5-high-level-java-rest-client-delete-an-index-by-name-is-not-wo/55529507#55529507) some classes can't be found. I guess they changed in ES 7.
The latest version 3.2.0.M4 of spring-boot-data-elastic supports ES 6.7.2, so it looks like we have to wait.

Comment: yes, it's not released for Spring Boot yet.

Comment: for my case I switched to using RestHighLevelClient by elastic instead of the spring data elastic search

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev here is a link to the pull request on GitHub. We have to wait I guess... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/284

Comment: As far as I can see it is meant to be supported in `Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.x` release. Anybody has idea about the estimated release date of that version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Spring Boot 2.3 is integrating spring-data-elasticsearch 4 so it will support ElasticSearch 7.x out of the box. It will be released soon but you can already try it:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RC1'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}
```

I have tested it positively and all of my test scenarios are passing so I would definitely recommend this way. I will keep the answer below for people that for some reasons can't upgrade to 2.3.

**OLD WORKAROUND** (previous versions original answer)

As we don`t really know when *Spring Data Elastic Search **4.x*** is going to be released I am posting my way of integrating the current  *Spring Data Elastic Search **4.x*** and stable *Spring Boot **2.1.7***. It might work as a temporary workaround for you if you want to work with the Spring Repositories and the newest Elastic Search.

1) Force newest elastic search client in your dependencies (in my case: **build.gradle**)

```
dependencies {
    //Force spring-data to use the newest elastic-search client
    //this should removed as soon as spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0 is released!
    implementation('org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch'
        exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin'
        exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch.client'
    }

    implementation('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.3.0') { force = true }
    implementation('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.3.0') { force = true }
    implementation('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.3.0') { force = true }
}
```

2) Disable the Elastic Search auto configuration and health check components as they become incompatible (you may later want to implement your own health check).

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

3) As we disabled the auto configuration we need to initialize the `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` ourselves. We also need to do it to provide the custom `MappingElasticsearchConverter` to avoid class incompatibilities.

```
/**
 * Manual configuration to support the newest ElasticSearch that is currently not supported by {@link org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration}.
 *
 * @author aleksanderlech
 */
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(ElasticsearchProperties configuration) {
        var nodes =  Stream.of(configuration.getClusterNodes().split(",")).map(HttpHost::create).toArray(HttpHost[]::new);
        var client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(nodes));
        var converter = new CustomElasticSearchConverter(new SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext(), createConversionService());
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client, converter, new DefaultResultMapper(converter));
    }

    private DefaultConversionService createConversionService() {
        var conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(new StringToLocalDateConverter());
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

CustomElasticSearchConverter:

```
/**
 * Custom version of {@link MappingElasticsearchConverter} to support newest Spring Data Elasticsearch integration that supports ElasticSearch 7. Remove when Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.x is released.
 */
class CustomElasticSearchConverter extends MappingElasticsearchConverter {

    private CustomConversions conversions = new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());

    CustomElasticSearchConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
        super(mappingContext);
        setConversions(conversions);
    }

    CustomElasticSearchConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext, GenericConversionService conversionService) {
        super(mappingContext, conversionService);
        setConversions(conversions);
    }

    @Override
    protected <R> R readValue(@Nullable Object source, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                              TypeInformation<R> targetType) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (source instanceof List) {
            return readCollectionValue((List) source, property, targetType);
        }

        return super.readValue(source, property, targetType);
    }

    private Object readSimpleValue(@Nullable Object value, TypeInformation<?> targetType) {

        Class<?> target = targetType.getType();

        if (value == null || target == null || ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(target, value)) {
            return value;
        }

        if (conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(value.getClass(), target)) {
            return getConversionService().convert(value, target);
        }

        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(target)) {
            return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) target, value.toString());
        }

        return getConversionService().convert(value, target);
    }


    private <R> R readCollectionValue(@Nullable List<?> source, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                                      TypeInformation<R> targetType) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Collection<Object> target = createCollectionForValue(targetType, source.size());

        for (Object value : source) {

            if (isSimpleType(value)) {
                target.add(
                        readSimpleValue(value, targetType.getComponentType() != null ? targetType.getComponentType() : targetType));
            } else {

                if (value instanceof List) {
                    target.add(readValue(value, property, property.getTypeInformation().getActualType()));
                } else {
                    target.add(readEntity(computeGenericValueTypeForRead(property, value), (Map) value));
                }
            }
        }

        return (R) target;
    }

    private Collection<Object> createCollectionForValue(TypeInformation<?> collectionTypeInformation, int size) {

        Class<?> collectionType = collectionTypeInformation.isCollectionLike()//
                ? collectionTypeInformation.getType() //
                : List.class;

        TypeInformation<?> componentType = collectionTypeInformation.getComponentType() != null //
                ? collectionTypeInformation.getComponentType() //
                : ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT;

        return collectionTypeInformation.getType().isArray() //
                ? new ArrayList<>(size) //
                : CollectionFactory.createCollection(collectionType, componentType.getType(), size);
    }

    private ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?> computeGenericValueTypeForRead(ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                                                                            Object value) {

        return ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT.equals(property.getTypeInformation().getActualType())
                ? getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(value.getClass())
                : getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(property.getTypeInformation().getActualType());
    }

    private boolean isSimpleType(Object value) {
        return isSimpleType(value.getClass());
    }

    private boolean isSimpleType(Class<?> type) {
        return conversions.isSimpleType(type);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Aleksander, thx, just tested your approach and it works fine for me. Previous issues with repositories findBy methods are gone. Nevertheless, one question: Do you just ignore the following warning?:  `[299 Elasticsearch-7.3.0-de777fa "[types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated` or do you have a solution for that?

Comment: This does not work for me. Throws: "ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.EntityInstantiators"

Comment: Probably you used a never snapshot, I am going to update my answer anyway as now its a better solution available

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using **Spring Boot 2.1.2** and **Kotlin**, the following code may help you. I just translated it from @Alexander Lech answer, with some small changes:

First change to Alexanders Answer:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration::class, 
ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration::class])
```

I had to exclude `ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration`, to make it work.

Second: Since we use Kotlin, and the custom converter is a lot of code, perhaps this translation to Kotlin will help somebody:

```
class CustomElasticSearchConverter(mappingContext: MappingContext<out ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<*>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty>, customConversionService: GenericConversionService?) : MappingElasticsearchConverter(mappingContext, customConversionService) {

    private val conversionsNew = ElasticsearchCustomConversions(emptyList<Any>())

    init {
        setConversions(conversionsNew)
    }

    override fun <R : Any?> readValue(source: Any?, property: ElasticsearchPersistentProperty, targetType: TypeInformation<R>): R? {
        if (source == null) {
            return null
        }

        if (source is Collection<*>) {
            return readCollectionValue(source, property, targetType) as R?;
        }

        return super.readValue(source, property, targetType);
    }

    private fun readCollectionValue(source: Collection<*>?, property: ElasticsearchPersistentProperty, targetType: TypeInformation<*>): Any? {

        if (source == null) {
            return null
        }

        val target = createCollectionForValue(targetType, source.size)

        for (value in source) {
            require(value != null) { "value must not be null" }

            if (isSimpleType(value)) {
                target.add(readSimpleValue(value, if (targetType.componentType != null) targetType.componentType!! else targetType))
            } else {
                if (value is MutableCollection<*>) {
                    target.add(readValue(value, property, property.typeInformation.actualType as TypeInformation<out Any>))
                } else {
                    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                    target.add(readEntity(computeGenericValueTypeForRead(property, value), value as MutableMap<String, Any>?))
                }
            }
        }

        return target
    }

    private fun readSimpleValue(value: Any?, targetType: TypeInformation<*>): Any? {

        val target = targetType.type

        @Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON")
        if (value == null || target == null || ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(target, value)) {
            return value
        }

        if (conversionsNew.hasCustomReadTarget(value.javaClass, target)) {
            return conversionService.convert(value, target)
        }

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return when {
            Enum::class.java.isAssignableFrom(target) -> enumByName(target as Class<Enum<*>>, value.toString())
            else -> conversionService.convert(value, target)
        }
    }

    private fun enumByName(target: Class<Enum<*>>, name: String): Enum<*> {
        val enumValue = target.enumConstants.find { it.name == name }
        require(enumValue != null) { "no enum value found for name $name and targetClass $target" }
        return enumValue
    }

    private fun createCollectionForValue(collectionTypeInformation: TypeInformation<*>, size: Int): MutableCollection<Any?> {

        val collectionType = when {
            collectionTypeInformation.isCollectionLike -> collectionTypeInformation.type
            else -> MutableList::class.java
        }

        val componentType = when {
            collectionTypeInformation.componentType != null -> collectionTypeInformation.componentType
            else -> ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT
        }

        return when {
            collectionTypeInformation.type.isArray -> ArrayList(size)
            else -> CollectionFactory.createCollection(collectionType, componentType!!.type, size)
        }
    }

    private fun computeGenericValueTypeForRead(property: ElasticsearchPersistentProperty, value: Any): ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<*> {

        return when {
            ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT == property.typeInformation.actualType -> mappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(value.javaClass)
            else -> mappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(property.typeInformation.actualType!!)
        }
    }

    private fun isSimpleType(value: Any): Boolean {
        return isSimpleType(value.javaClass)
    }

    private fun isSimpleType(type: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return conversionsNew.isSimpleType(type)
    }

}
```

After this, problems with some repository queries where solved. Please also be aware not to use `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` but `spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. (This took me some time).

Yes, the code is ugly, but after `spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0` is released, you can throw it away.

Comment: Hi ,

I am trying to use the code mentioned above but I am getting the following error
    
`2019-11-26 14:33:45,287 ERROR [restartedMain] org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=No type specified for field [properties]]`

Comment: OK, first of all I noticed, that using 4.0.0-SNAPHOST is a bit unsable, I would recommend to use "4.0.0.DATAES-690-SNAPSHOT", because the 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT changes too often. Second, to your problem: It seams that you are using an uknown type in your @Document and you need to annotate it with `@Field(type = FieldType.<AnyfieldType>)`. Perhaps that could help your mapping.