# How can I use Spring Data ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.1.0 and I want to create a spring-boot application and connect with elasticsearch using spring-data-elastic-search. But I have not found a solution to use query and aggregation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, spring data elasticsearch does not support version 7.1.0 yet. See versions section in this link:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

You could see if it it works by connecting to this version but it wouldn't be a supported solution. The best suggestion would be to use a version of elasticsearch that is supported by spring data elasticsearch e.g. elasticsearch 3.2.x supports version 6.7.2 of elasticsearch. This should work fine then.

Comment: running spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.x against ES 7 does *not* work. No need  to try this.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a dummy rest-api project using spring boot and elasticsearch-data.
You can take the reference from here-

https://github.com/haritmaljhain/working-api.git

If you have any issue, let me know.

Comment: this links to something non-existent

Comment: Its working and accessible, kindly recheck the links.

Comment: as I wqrote in my answer, Spring Data Elasticsearch currently does not support Elasticsearch 7.x

Comment: Yes...you are absolutely correct I am using elasticsearch-6.4.3 . Sir, I have not tested it with 7.x

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible, after `spring-data-elasticsearch:4.0.0` was released, but there is not even a milestone for that. The newest `spring-boot version 2.2.1` with the corresponding starter for `data-elasticsearch` uses `spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.1`

Until 4.0.0 is released, you can use the following workaround:

[How to integrate ElasticSearch 7.0 version with Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761140/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-7-0-version-with-spring-boot)