# configuration Elasticsearch to java SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

I am trying to configure  Elastic to SpringBoot Application with  Jdk 1.8 and elastic search Versi7.6.61
   and Current spring version 2.2.5.RELEASE

```
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/>
```

//these are pom for elastic search

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>
```

currently, I am using the latest release of Elasticsearch version 7.6.1
    I got the following the Java JDK version is 1.8  Exception

```
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchRestHighLevelClient' defined in class path resource \[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/rest/RestClientConfigurations$RestHighLevelClientConfiguration.class\]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class \[org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient\] from ClassLoader \[sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~\[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~\[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~\[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) \[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) \[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) \[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) \[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) \[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at io.dz.ReIndexing.main(ReIndexing.java:13) \[classes/:na\]
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class \[org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient\] from ClassLoader \[sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2\]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~\[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~\[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310) ~\[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:569) ~\[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            ... 15 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/Cancellable
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~\[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE\]
            ... 22 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.client.Cancellable
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~\[na:1.8.0_161\]
            ... 26 common frames omitted


//when I am trying to configure Elastic search I got the Exception class not Found 
thanks in Advance to reply][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you paste segment of your pom.xml which mentions how your have added dependency of ElasticSearch in your project

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @Purushottam please add the content of pom to question so that its easy to read

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant I add the elastic search dependency

Comment: @Purushottam This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470686/elasticsearch6-5-high-level-java-rest-client-delete-an-index-by-name-is-not-wo/55529507#55529507) might help.

Answer (score 3):

The **high-level REST client**  which you have added internally calls low-level REST client

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>
```

This , low level client is loaded by core dependency itself, but it seems it does not correspond to version 7.x (You can check the same in your external libraries list).

In my system `elastcsearch-rest-client` that got added was of version 6.4.2 while I was using `elastcisearch` of version 7.5.0

[image]

So, in this case you can add dependency related to `elasticsearch-rest-client` manually in pom.xml by adding :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId> org.elasticsearch.client </ groupId>
  <artifactId> elasticsearch-rest-client </ artifactId>
  <version>${org.elasticsearch}</ version>
</ dependency>
```

So, your complete  pom.xml related to elastic search dependencies should look like :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId> org.elasticsearch.client </ groupId>
      <artifactId> elasticsearch-rest-client </ artifactId>
      <version>${org.elasticsearch}</ version>
</ dependency>
```

Comment: @Purushottam If your issue is resolved, can you accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using springboot with elasticsearch, you need to be explicit with some transitive dependencies as SpringBoot declares a version 6.4...

Basically you can put this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <elasticsearch.version>7.6.1<elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
```

See documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-dependency-versions